# Running mlflow ui in AWS Sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, mlflow

I want to run mlflow UI in sagemaker but it simply does not work, When it outputs the http address going to it results in a "this site cannot be reached"

Here is the code:

```
def mlflow_test(server_uri, experiment_name):
    mlflow.set_tracking_uri(server_uri)
    mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name)
    with mlflow.start_run():
        params = {
            "n-estimators": 100,
            "min-samples-leaf": 10,
            "features": 'feature_test'
        }
        mlflow.log_params(params)
        mlflow.log_metric('foo', 5)
        mlflow.end_run()
```

running that code will return:

```
[2022-05-24 15:48:44 +0000] [27820] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-05-24 15:48:44 +0000] [27820] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (27820)
[2022-05-24 15:48:44 +0000] [27820] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-05-24 15:48:44 +0000] [27823] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27823
```

Going to the http://127.0.0.1:5000 link won't work. Anyone know how to get mlflow ui running in sagemaker? There's not much info on this that's at an easy to understand level. I just want to log my metrics and params in sagemaker and view them using the mlflow ui

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in SageMaker Studio or a Classic Notebook Instance? You could technically use the Studio terminal to try launch MLflow, but I would not recommend this. It would be better to setup something like this on EC2 where you have full control over the setup of your environment.